# How to use a blob to display an image in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, blob

So, in the database I have an image and I retrieve it as a blob. I'm trying to display it this way:

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        const divImagen = document.getElementById('txt_2914');

        const valorBlob = divImagen.getAttribute('data-formulario-valueprev');

        const blob = new Blob([valorBlob], { type: 'image/jpeg' }); 


        const shownImage = document.createElement('img');
        shownImage.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);


        divImagen.appendChild(shownImage);
    });
```

but this doesn't work. It just shows me this
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJorf.png)

any ideas how to fix this? thank you!